# Python iterating dictionary and delete item

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I have a dictionary from which i want to delete items like this:

```
for key1 in d.keys():
        for key2 in d.keys():
            if len(set(d[key1]) & set(d[key2])) > 0:
                 del d[key2]
```

But I get an error: KeyError. I am using Python 2.7, if someone knows how is it possible to do this, i'm waiting for your answer.
My dictionary looks like:

```
{("a", "1") : ["c1", "c2", "c3"], ("b", "2") : ["c4", "c5"]}
```

Comment: Explain what you want to do in English. Since your code is wrong, it doesn't serve as a good explanation of your intent.

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense, 2 keys in a dictionary can't be equal by definition. What are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: I have edited the post, sorry, my bad.

Comment: Post an example value of `d` and the traceback.

Comment: Actually, if you put two equal keys in a dictionary, it doesn't cause an error, so it is possible to have duplicate keys in a dictionary, at least in python2.7.

Comment: @kaisquared No, one value overwrites the other. You only end up with one value for the key.

Comment: @kaisquared No, it's not. The second assignment will simply override the first.

Comment: What version of Python? Also, nice MVCE. +1

Comment: Sorry, my mistake then.

Comment: `len(set(d[key1]) & set(d[key2])) > 0` can be replaced with `len(set(d[key1]) & set(d[key2]))`, `set(d[key1]) & set(d[key2])`, or `not set(d[key1]).isdisjoint(d[key2])`

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Don't just post code that doesn't work. Describe the actual problem so we can offer better solutions. Also please read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: What should the behavior be for this dict: `{("a", "1") : ["c1", "c2", "c3"], ("b", "2") : ["c4", "c5", "c1"],  ("c", "3") : ["c4", "c5"]}`? There's a lot of fiddly cases here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Alex Hall's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37220649/1394393) points out, the problem is that you're trying to access a key that you just deleted.

The first problem here is that you're not skipping the case when `key1 == key2`. When this happens, the intersection will *always* have elements. You want to avoid that. So:

```
for key1 in d.keys():
    for key2 in d.keys():
        if key1 != key2 and len(set(d[key1]) & set(d[key2])) > 0:
             del d[key2]
```

This fixes your loop for the case where they are no common elements. But there are more problems. Consider this `dict`, for instance:

```
{("a", "1") : ["c1", "c2", "c3"], ("b", "2") : ["c4", "c5", "c1"]}
```

This tries to delete `("b", 2)`, but by the time the *outer* loop moves on to `("b", "2")`, it's already been deleted. So you need to skip that case:

```
for key1 in d.keys():
    if key1 in d:
        for key2 in d.keys():
            if key1 != key2 and len(set(d[key1]) & set(d[key2])) > 0:
                del d[key2]
```

This gives us what we wanted, the latter element removed:

```
{('a', '1'): ['c1', 'c2', 'c3']}
```

But... There's a lot of weird cases to think about, still. What about this one?

```
{("a", "1") : ["c1", "c2", "c3"], ("b", "2") : ["c4", "c5", "c1"],  ("c", "3") : ["c4", "c5"]}
```

This one depends on *what order* you delete things in, and you can't rely on any key order in a `dict`. So the question arises, what exactly are you really trying to accomplish? Shoving everything into a `dict` and eliminating anything with common elements can result in unpredictable results. So this probably isn't a good way to accomplish what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You try to delete while iterating over that same collection. That's never a good idea. Consider this approach instead:

**Update** first idea was a bit buggy.

Or a bit simplified as suggested by @Alex Hall in the comments:

```
from itertools import combinations

keys_pairs = combinations(d.keys(), 2)
keys_to_delete = set()
for key1, key2 in keys_pairs:
    if len(set(d[key1]) & set(d[key2])) > 0:
        keys_to_delete.add(key2)
for key in keys_to_delete:
    d.pop(key)
```

Comment: `permutations` is perhaps overkill at this level.

Comment: Actually your idea of ignoring `KeyError` is good enough. OP simply needs to do that on the `if` in the original code and it should work as intended.

Comment: @AlexHall Yeah, catching the `KeyError` will probably help OP, but there are always edge cases where deleting while iterating can pose a problem, so I just wanted to point that out.

Comment: Are you sure this works? The reason you have to do `except KeyError` is because you're getting dupes in `keys_to_delete`. How do you know you're not removing *both* copies of the thing you want to keep one of?

Comment: True. Also `permutations` will produce both `(a,b)` and `(b,a)` which is redundant. Use `combinations`. And you can do without the `try` if `keys_to_delete` is a set.

Comment: @AlexHall Thanks. Added that as an option.

Comment: This removes both keys when there's a common element: `{("a", "1") : ["c1", "c2", "c3"], ("b", "2") : ["c4", "c5", "c1"]}`. Passing that through gives you an empty `dict`.

Comment: @jpmc26 My original post indeed removed both keys sometimes. The one I have now works fine.

Comment: `d = {("a", "1") : ["c1", "c2", "c3"], ("b", "2") : ["c4", "c5", "c1"],  ("c", "3") : ["c4", "c5"]}`. You lose the last element with this one. I've asked in comment on question for the OP to clarify what the behavior should be.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to debug something, print things.

```
for key1 in d.keys():
    print 'key1', key1
    print 'inner d.keys', d.keys()
    for key2 in d.keys():
        print 'key2', key2
        if len(set(d[key1]) & set(d[key2])) > 0:
            del d[key2]
            print 'deleted, new d.keys', d.keys()

key1 ('a', '1')
inner d.keys [('a', '1'), ('b', '2')]
key2 ('a', '1')
deleted, new d.keys [('b', '2')]
key2 ('b', '2')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alexhall/Dropbox/python/sandbox/sandbox.py", line 8, in <module>
    if len(set(d[key1]) & set(d[key2])) > 0:
KeyError: ('a', '1')
```

That is, it asks for `d[key1]` but it can't because it was just deleted.

Comment: Now that I'm looking at it, why is this loop deleting anything? The lists (the values) have no common elements. Heck, the keys don't either.

Comment: @jpmc26 in the first iteration `key1` and `key2` are the same key